# How to pass object values in decimals in api React js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native

Issue is: The JsonObject drops the trailing zero from the REST request input, when the type is a decimal.

**Example:
If the Customer.Balance field has the following value:**

> Balance        465.000

```
The JSON sent wil be:
“Customer": [
        {
          "CustNum": 1,
          "Balance": 465, 
        }]
```

**But to process the request at server side we need number as decimal type only**

Output required

```
“Customer": [
        {
          "CustNum": 1,
          "Balance": “465.000”, 
        }]
```

Kindly suggest us some way to process these kinds of requests

Comment: 465 is exactly the same as 465.000 unless you want to think mathematically about precision. If you want to show it as 465.000 then you’ll have to send it as a string. Why do you need to process it with the decimals exactly?

Comment: Yes i  have tried to do as string but on the server side, then we need to parse that object again that won't help, I have try so many solution can you help me in thtat

Comment: function includeDecimal(x) {
  return Number.parseFloat(x).toFixed(2);
}

Comment: https://github.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js

Comment: Please let me now apart from that way above metioned

Comment: But *why* does the number need a specific amount of decimals if it’s being handled as a number anyway? It doesn’t matter if it’s 465, 465.0, 465.00 or 465.000 because they are the same exact number. Please explain the actual problem here.

Comment: I know we cannot convert but our db has setup this kind of situation that's why i needd this, but as i can see this cannot be resolve

Answer (score 1):

How about sending it as string and then parse it from string to intezer!

This will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the Client side use the class and send the object of that class in the request.
for example -

```
class Request {
  constructor(CustNum, Balance) {
    this.CustNum = CustNum;
    this.Balance = Balance;
  }
}
const {CustNum, Balance} = this.props; //some way to get it

Axios.post("some URL", {
   params : new Request(CustNum, Balance)
})
```

Comment: Can you please add some more code in that, how can it be work in api object, i shall be thankful to you